# c++ not writing to console unless a newline was encountered

Tags: c++, constructor, newline, stdout

I was recently writing a simple c++ program involving sockets. It had been a while since I worked with c++, so i was doing some simple sanity checking to make sure my classes were properly constructed. I encountered a very strange error then. When I did not have `\n` or `endl` at the end of my output to console, it would not write to console. For example:

This would not output to console

```
class Server{
    public:
        Server(){
            std::cout << "STARTING SERVER";
        }
};
```

This would:

```
class Server{
    public:
        Server(){
            std::cout << "STARTING SERVER" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Both were created using `Server server;`. Was this just a 'ghost' in my computer or has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's normal. It's stored in the buffer until the buffer is flushed. You can send `std::flush` to the stream to flush it. You can use `std::endl` to write an end of line and flush the buffer. It's basically an optimization to avoid large numbers of I/O operations if you write lots of small things to a stream.

Comment: Automatically flushing on a full line is a new one for me. It flushes on `endl` because it's equivalent to `'\n'` plus `flush`.

Comment: Maybe add a  `std::cout << "foo" << std::flush;` or a `std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;` to your answer for completeness and giving newbies a hint